# saveurl on createrecordevent or navigationlocation in lightning component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, sfdc

I have a similar code as below.

```
createRecord : function (component) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Case",
    "panelOnDestroyCallback": function(event) {
           $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject").setParams({
                   recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
                   slideDevName: "detail"
            }).fire();
     }
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

It does not redirect to the record id i have provided and this code is not even calling the function inside "panelOnDestroyCallback".

I have also tried "navigationLocation": "LOOKUP" and I do know RELATED_LIST opens the same page i have called the createrecordevent.

I have also tried url redirect too inside that "panelOnDestroyCallback".

panelOnDestroyCallback is not even getting called in the code.

**My intention is to send the page to account record detail page after it saved the case record which was opened from createrecordevent??**

Answer (score 0):

`e.force:createRecord` will automatically redirect you to the new record after creation. No need to define a custom callback for that.

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:button label="Create Case" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.createRecord}"/>
</aura:component>
```

```js
({
    createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");

        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Case"
        });

        createRecordEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: I apologize if i am not clear, i want it to open account detail page not case record page. i do have account record id in the code too.